# indicator-multiload (I/O wait)

Tags: lubuntu, indicator, cpu

I´ve installed indicator-multiload in order to be able to monitor my network and cpu. Using indicator-multiload I noticed that the browsers (firefox as well as midori) cause a relatively high
cpu-load.

This is when I open a new tab and contents are loading. Sometimes it happens that at least some reactions of the PC freeze for a few seconds.
To be more precise: The actual cpu-load ("system") isn´t high at all. It´s rather what is called "I/O wait" that is really high (sometimes up to roundabout 70%).
As soon as the respective page is fully loaded everything is back to normal again and the whole system is responsive like it was before.
Of course this behaviour is dependent on the contents of the page. Just text or only few pictures mean no lag.

I want to add that I dont´t use any swap, neither as a separate partition  nor as a swap-file. 
And: my system is installed on a USB-stick (64GB), USB 2.0
Yet I don´t know whether this has anything to with it.

My question is: Is there a way of manipulating the aforementioned behaviour, i.e. can I change in any way the cpu-behaviour with regard to "I/O wait"?

Rosika

P.S.: 
system: Linux/Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, 64bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made similar observations with the system partition (Lubuntu 14.04) on a USB drive (rather than a live system). It's not without problems unfortunately.

Many USB sticks (USB2.0 in particular) are quite slow with writing, and even if they have a decent speed when writing large files, some might become very slow with scattered writes of small blocks (with ext4 filesystems many 8k blocks are written). What happens then is that the system's write queue gets congested and applications are stuck waiting for a long time for their writes to finish (that's the state shown as "I/O wait"), even when they were only writing a few bytes to a logfile. When this happens to e.g. the panel app, the entire desktop may "freeze".

What helped somewhat was disabling the disk cache in firefox, and other things that might write to disk a lot. In a standard system unfortunately a lot of stuff is writing to disk all the time.

I investigated this using "iostat -x 1" (shows the state of disk I/O in general) and "iotop". The latter hels with identifying processes that write to disk a lot.

I also played around with different disk schedulers and their settings, but it didn't really help a lot so I won't get into detail here.

I actually had two cheap(ish) USB 3.0 drives that died from this kind of use after a few months or a year, apparently they are not made for being written to a lot (flash memory will wear out from a lot of writing, in particular if the filesystem is not optimized for flash).

The only thing that really helped was getting a good high-quality USB drive that can support the write load. What you want to look for in particular is decent write performance (at least several MB/sec) for small (8K) block sizes. I'm now using a SanDisk Extreme USB 3.0 32MB, stick which apparently uses an SSD controller - so much more sophisticated optimization/wear leveling and better write performance than the usual USB drives. It also has some limited SMART support, so at least it won't fail without warning if you have an eye on it.
They are usually quite expensive, but I found some relatively cheap 'refurb' ones on chinese ebay. Not intending a commercial plug here, there are probably others with similar performance.

Another option might be to use f2fs ("flash friendly file system") on the system partition, but I have not tried or investigated this.

Comment: Hi rai42. Tnx for your lengthy and thorough answer which contains lots of good ideas. F2FS looks interesting for USB-sticks. I´ll have to look into it for further info. You´re certainly right in saying that most USB-sticks aren´t perfect due to a lot of writing operations. As a matter of fact I had to replace my stick as well. Now I´m using a WD  Elements 25A2 external HDD, though still via my USB2.0 port. Yet it has an external power supply and works stable. In the beginning I used the USB-stick as it was an experimental project at the time. Now with the HDD I use it as a productive system.